# How to open same file paths for edit & checkout?

Tags: perforce, vcs-checkout

I have an ongoing product with p4 version control. I have the need to edit same files every time. (different version of the product)

I want to be able to check out and open same files without using scripts.

Is there any way I can do it in some p4 plugin or p4 configuration?

Example:

```
/version_50/user/eng/fileExample.cpp

/version_51/user/eng/fileExample.cpp

/version_52/user/eng/fileExample.cpp
```

I want a simple button to check out same file.

Comment: Button where?  Do you mean in p4v?  If you want the same files perpetually open, you can use `p4 submit -r` when submitting to re-open the submitted files.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Is there an option to automatically check the file out when editing? There is in Visual Studio for example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening files for edit (checking them out) you could work on them, then use:

p4 reconcile

to keep track of the changes.

More information about this command is available here:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_reconcile.html

Hope this helps,
Jen.